# Apply git fork for distinct repositories?

Tags: git, git-fork

The project I'm working, `repo A` was copied (not forked) and used as a base in a different project, `repo B`. These are now two distinct repositories, with completely distinct histories and no common commit. `repo B` is now 800 commits in and `repo A` is 60 commits in.

```
repo A   
 - CA1 - CA2 - ... - CA60
 
repo B
 - CB1 - CB2 - ... - CB800

where CA is a commit on repo A, and CB is a commit on repo B.   
Note that there is no common commit, since the files were copied, instead of forking 
the repo.
```

Now that the problem was discovered, we want to configure `repo B` as a fork of `repo A`, apply all changes from `repo A` and then apply the changes of `repo B`. The result should look like this:

```
fork repo A
 - CA1 - CA2 - ... - CA60 - CB1 - CB2 - ... - CB800
```

**Initial thoughts**

Initially, I though of creating patches of the 800 commits of `repo B` and apply them on a `forked repo A`. However, considering that the source files are no longer the same, and that each patch file would need manual changes, this is a tedious task and certainly not error proof.

Then I thought of trying the other way around and applying the commits from `repo A` to `repo B`, but while this isn't so tedious, there wouldn't be a correspondence between the original commits in `repo A` and those applied to `repo B` because now `repo B` has its own changes.

**Current thoughts**

So now I'm thinking of creating a fork of `repo A` and then slowly and painfully integrate the changed files (not the commits), of `repo B` into the new repository and thus recreate the repository. This would result in:

```
fork repo A
 - CA60 - CN1 - CN2 - ... -CNN

where CN is a new commit to replicate the functionalities of repo B
```

It's just sad ...

**Question**

Is there a better way for configuring `repo B` as fork for the latest `repo A` and then applying the changes of `repo B`? Keep in mind they share *no common commit*.

Comment: If the two repositories share a common history, you should be able to include them both in the same repository and then use `git rebase` to apply the changes from B onto A. How much of an effort this is depends on the nature of those 60 commits in A; it might be easier than you think. I would try that first before you being pursuing other options.

Comment: They don't share a common history, but only a common state. The history was lost when the files of `repo B` were simply copied from `repo A`. Should I edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: I think the wording of the initial paragraph strongly suggests that they have simply diverged, not that you discarded the repository history when you copied it. An update might help.

Comment: Having said that, what I said about rebasing applies equally well to patching: if you `git format-patch` to create patches for your 800 commits and then apply them with `git am`, there's a good chance the process might be less painful than you think.

Comment: @larsks I edited the question. The problem with patches is that I would have to edit each individual patch, since `repo A` has changes of its own.

I added some graphs to make this clearer. And thanks for taking interest in this question!

Comment: If you don't need _both_ repos' git histories, why not just copy the files from repo B back into A, then commit only the changes you want to keep in repo A?

Comment: @NRitH that is more or less my current way of thinking. But I won't just copy the files, but adapt them to the new `repo A` structure.

Comment: looks like it's something you would use `cd repoB && git remote add repoA && git merge repoA  main --allow-unrelated-histories`